# Prevent _vti_bin/owssvr.dll? from displaying the 'item type' and 'path' column

Tags: 2007

**The Situation**

I have a button that call `http://mywebsite.com/subsite/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List={LIST_ID_REMOVED}&View={VIEW_ID_REMOVED}&CacheControl=1`

In the SharePoint 2007 View itself, I only have 2 columns - Title and Description. However, when I click the button, it will open Excel with 2 more extra columns - Item Type and Path.

**Question**

What should I do to the link such that when I click the button, it only show the 2 columns - Title and Description rather than 4 columns (which include Item Type and Path column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1) Create a new file in notepad and copy in it:

```
http://mywebsite.com/subsite/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?XMLDATA=1&List={LIST_ID_REMOVED}&View={VIEW_ID_REMOVED}
```

2) Save the file as *owssvr.iqy* (please note the extension)

3) Upload this file to a document library and use its link in the button instead.

Comment: I tried the same but it is giving me the error, "data could not be retrieved from the database check the database server or contact your database administrator. Make sure external database is available, and then try operation again. Sharepoint list export error"

Comment: How can i implement the same for sharepoint 2013 list

Answer (score 0):

The way Sharepoint defines the content of the `.iqy` file is the below:

```
WEB
1
${base}/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?XMLDATA=1&List=${params.List}&View=${params.View}&RowLimit=0&RootFolder=${encodeURIComponent(params.RootFolder)}

Selection=${params.List}-${params.View}
EditWebPage=
Formatting=None
PreFormattedTextToColumns=True
ConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne=True
SingleBlockTextImport=False
DisableDateRecognition=False
DisableRedirections=False
SharePointApplication=${base}/_vti_bin
SharePointListView=${params.View}
SharePointListName=${params.List}
RootFolder=${params.RootFolder}
```

I tried to change several of those parameters, and the only way I found to remove columns `path` and `item type` is to remove the last 4 lines:

```
// to remove
SharePointApplication=${base}/_vti_bin
SharePointListView=${params.View}
SharePointListName=${params.List}
RootFolder=${params.RootFolder}
```

However, by doing it, the columns are not formatted anymore. For example, a people picker columns will return `ID;#Name`  instead of just the `Name`.

On the web we can find various parameters to add in the URL but none of them as produced the correct format.

To make the things easy to deal with, and to remove the `path` and `item type`, and if you don't have any `lookup` column, then the best approach is to use the below URL provided by [Amit](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/21696/17341):
[http://mywebsite.com/subsite/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?XMLDATA=1&List={LIST_ID_REMOVED}&View={VIEW_ID_REMOVED}](http://mywebsite.com/subsite/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?XMLDATA=1&List=%7BLIST_ID_REMOVED%7D&View=%7BVIEW_ID_REMOVED%7D)

After additional research, I found a Microsoft Doc about the parameters in the URL: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms478653(v=office.14)

The columns `item type` and `path` are probably automatically added by Excel because it gets a XML feed.